# how can I split a string and store it in a temporary variable

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, tornado

I have a data, which is nothing but a string **b'365,7,7675962680, 4040**.I want to split this data and want to store only **7675962680** to any temporary variable.I don not know, how to split and pick that particular data in python. I have a small code, please help me to solve these issue

manage.py

```
def data(self, data):
    data1 = data # b'365,7,7675962680, 4040
    # want to split these and store 7675962680 in a variable
```

Comment: Note the question about "convert a string to ip address" - it looks like you're working on the same exercise at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
def get_data(data):
    data = data.decode()
    data_list = data.split(',')
    return data_list[2]

a = get_data(b'365,7,7675962680, 4040')
print(a)
>> 7675962680
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming,

```
s ="365,7,7675962680, 4040"
s.split(',')[2]
'7675962680'
```

Comment: Be careful! `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 0):

```
def data(self, data):
    # data = b'365,7,7675962680, 4040
    # data MUST be converted to str before splitting it
    data1 = data.decode('utf8').split(',')[2]
    print(data1)  # 7675962680
    print(type(data1))  # str
```